# How to return state of a process in Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, process, expect

I have the following Expect file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set processid[lindex $argv 3]

set command "ps -q $processid -o state --no-headers"

spawn ssh -t  test@192.168.94.139 $command

expect {...}
```

I need to get the state of a process having its pid; however, it's giving me the following error:

```
 List of process IDs must follow -q.
```

And sometimes this error:

```
TTY could not be found
```

Knowing that when I try this command (that list all processes) it works perfectly:

```
set commands "ps -eo pid,comm,lstart --sort=-start_time"
```

Wondering what is my error! How can I make it work?

Thanks :)

Comment: Drop the -t ....

Comment: Your shebang says `bash`, but that looks like an `expect` script, which is TCL.

Comment: Hey @jordanm yes sorry I copied pasted it from another script. I corrected it.

Comment: You need a space between `set processid` and `[lindex $argv 3]`

Comment: @glennjackman and the way I'm calling the variable processid is good? because I saw somewhere written that it should be in quotations (as "processid"), but I have also the other quotations for the command!

Comment: This is fine for a Tcl/expect script. For _shell_ scripts, quoting is much more important.